# Programmatically adding tags to Data Catalog Custom entries

Tags: google-data-catalog

I am trying to attach tags to data catalog custom entries. I am trying to create a python function to perform data catalog operations i.e. create/delete custom entries, create/delete tag templates, attach tags to the fields of the created custom entries.

I was able to create a custom entry and a  tag template using the datacatalog_v1 library, however I don't find a method or a rest API to attach the tags fields to the custom entry columns.

I am however able to complete via the GCP web UI console

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Actually I was already able too create the entry groups and entries using the rest api and python libraries. The question was  ore on creating tags on the specific columns of the entry.

I did find an api https://datacatalog.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/entryGroups/{entry_group_id}/entries/{entry_id}/tags to perform the action but the json body was tricky.

In the end I was able to create tags one column at a time using the above POST call but could not figure out how to use the same for tagging multiple columns at a time

Comment: Hi Trishit, I added another part to my response that explains that you can use tag templates to achieve the multi tagging part that you are trying to do, if you could check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could see the next couple of examples on how to work with a data catalog REST API, and refer to the documentation that Google provides [here](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/custom-entries#create_entry_groups_and_custom_entries).

1. Create an entry group

Before using any of the request data, make the following replacements:

> 1. project-id: Your GCP project ID
> 2. entryGroupId: The ID must begin with a letter or underscore, contain only English letters, numbers and underscores, and be at most
>    64 characters.
>
> 3.displayName: The textual name for the entry group.

HTTP method and URL:

```
POST https://datacatalog.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/entryGroups?entryGroupId=entryGroupId
```

Request JSON body:

```
{
  "displayName": "Entry Group display name"
}
```

Save the request body in a file called request.json, and execute the following command:

```
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

Invoke-WebRequest `
 -Method POST `
 -Headers $headers `
 -ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
 -InFile request.json `
 -Uri "https://datacatalog.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/entryGroups?entryGroupId=entryGroupId" | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

You should receive a JSON response similar to the following:

```
{
  "name": "projects/my_projectid/locations/us-central1/entryGroups/my_entry_group",
  "displayName": "Entry Group display name",
  "dataCatalogTimestamps": {
    "createTime": "2019-10-19T16:35:50.135Z",
    "updateTime": "2019-10-19T16:35:50.135Z"
  }
}
```

You can structure your tags by topic using [tag templates](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/tags-and-tag-templates#tag-templates). For example:

> 1. A data governance tag with fields for: data governor, retention date, deletion date, PII (yes or no), data classification (public,
>    confidential, sensitive, regulatory)
> 2. A data quality tag with fields for: quality issues, update frequency, SLO information
> 3. A data usage tag with fields for: top users, top queries, average daily users